# What are the differences between multi-link suspensions and double-wishbone suspensions?

Tags: suspension, tuning

There are a multiple of different kinds of suspension, multi-link suspensions and double-wishbone are popular in some performance groups.  What are the main difference between these two?  What advantages and disadvantages does each offer over the other?

Comment: This is one of the proposed questions at the Area 51 proposal [Motorsports & Performance Tuning](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66334) It is offered here to gauge if that proposal is in fact [a duplicate of this site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13794)

Comment: This is a very broad question: for example, which two specific suspensions are you comparing? Without more specificity, a perfectly reasonable answer to the first question would be "geometry" and the second would be "it depends."  However, if you were to ask something more specific, it might be more useful: e.g., "Which better preserves camber throughout the various g-loads in a corner?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the obvious bits, the difference is that a multi-link suspension allows you to adjust one setting independently from the rest, e.g. camber, caster, toe in/out and ride height, giving you greater control over the final setup. Dual wishbone suspensions on the other hand don't offer quite as much flexibility, but they make up for it by being pretty good from the start.

Some people claim that multi-link setups are more forgiving when driving over bumpy surfaces, and I have no reason to argue with them, but I personally believe that has more to do with relative spring and compression rates as well as shock absorber type than anything else. In other words, I don't think you'll feel much of a difference between the two setups in the same car if they are tuned for the exact same conditions.